# Use Perl to loop over files and calculate the mean of each column

Tags: perl, find

I'm new to perl and I would like to lean how to use loops with it. I have multiple directories and each directory contain a file named data.txt. The data.txt file has several columns. I basically need to use a loop to calculate the mean of each column for each data.txt file.

I have this command that does the job for one single file:

```
perl -lane 'for $c (0..$#F){$t[$c] += $F[$c]}; END{for $c (0..$#t){print $t[$c]/$.}}' data.txt`
```

I wish to write a script where I visit every directory, read every file that's in it and apply the command.

Example:

data.txt:

```
-79.2335  0.4041    71.9143  1.3392    -0.7687  0.0212    -8.0934  1.1425 
-74.4163  0.6188    60.0468  1.8782    -0.8540  0.0305    -15.1574  1.4755 
-74.4118  0.6046    62.1771  1.8058    -0.9143  0.0304    -13.2272  1.3408 
-74.3895  0.5935    66.4264  1.6532    -0.8509  0.0223    -8.8819  1.2670 
-74.3192  0.5589    67.1619  1.4763    -0.9656  0.0274    -8.1090  1.1450 
-73.8272  0.6274    61.6632  1.7554    -0.8840  0.0256    -13.0435  1.3641 
-73.3525  0.5856    60.6622  1.7872    -0.8489  0.0222    -13.5014  1.3947 
-73.3206  0.6275    53.3129  2.2961    -0.7962  0.0337    -20.8195  1.8538 
-72.5461  0.5212    62.0359  1.4267    -0.9378  0.0240    -11.4203  1.0295 
-72.3058  0.7225    56.2304  2.1480    -0.7539  0.0293    -16.7954  1.5952 
-72.1180  0.6460    51.7954  2.0845    -0.8479  0.0265    -21.0355  1.4630 
-72.0690  0.4905    58.8372  1.3918    -0.9866  0.0333    -14.1823  1.1045 
-71.7949  0.5799    55.6006  1.9189    -0.8541  0.0313    -17.0112  1.4530 
-71.3074  0.4482    45.9271  2.1135    -0.6637  0.0354    -25.9309  1.8761 
-71.2542  0.4879    57.3196  1.5406    -0.9523  0.0281    -14.9113  1.2705 
-71.2421  0.5480    47.9065  2.2445    -0.8107  0.0352    -24.2489  1.7997 
-70.3751  0.5278    49.5489  1.8395    -0.8208  0.0371    -21.5205  1.4994 
-69.2181  0.4823    54.8234  1.0645    -0.9897  0.0246    -15.3506  0.9369 
-69.0456  0.4650    40.3798  2.0117    -0.6476  0.0360    -29.3403  1.7013 
-66.5402  0.5006    42.1805  1.7872    -0.7692  0.0356    -25.1431  1.4522
```

Output:

```
-72.354355   0.552015   56.297505   1.77814   -0.845845   0.029485   -16.88618   1.408235
```

Comment: Does it have to be one-liner?

Comment: The ouput shows the mean value of each column (sorry the input is displayed in a messy way). So, yes, I wish to have the values displayed in one line.

Comment: @mpg He means does the code have to be a one-liner. Or can it be a program file.

Comment: Maybe you should talk more about your directory structure. Do you need a recursive search, or can you get away with something like `*/data.txt`?

Comment: Do you want to specify the precision on the floating numbers, or is it ok if some of them become very long, like for example `120.333333333333333`?

Comment: This might be a task for the `find` command, e.g. `find . -name "data.txt" -exec perl .... {} \;` or some such. Then you use `find` to find the file with a recursive search, and use your Perl one-liner to process the file. You may need to add something to print the file name. I'm not very good with the find tool, but I added the flag to the question, maybe someone else can fill you in.

Comment: For example https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12902/108832

Comment: Sorry, I guess i misunderstood the question.

Comment: @mpg I gave you some feedback above, look into it and come back with new information.

Comment: It doesn't have to a be one liner in that case. As for my directory structure, I actually have a directory called mean with more than 100 sub-directories called differently. In each of these sub-directories, there is a data. txt file. I named all the files the same (data.txt), so it can be easy to process. So, my goal is to enter the directory (mean/) then each of the sub-directories to reach each file (data.txt) and calculate the mean where it can be stored in a seperate output file. I can show you an example with a bash script if that makes it easier.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the code generates very long floats.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'm going to try what was suggested before and come back with some feedback!

Comment: Make sure to add relevant info to your question with the "edit" button. Comments can be deleted by mods and users, and long comment threads make some people's fingers itch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your comments imply that you have a simple directory structure with one main directory called `mean` with 100s of subdirectories, each with a file called `data.txt`, the list of files can be compiled easily with a glob, and the math is fairly straightforward. This is a suggestion how it can be done.

I would not use `$.` as a way to calculate the average, since it can be corrupted by other factors. But just use a count variable for each file, and count the non-blank lines.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

for my $data (glob "mean/*/data.txt") {    # get list of files
    open my $fh, '<', $data or die "Cannot open file '$data': $!";
    my @sum;
    my $count = 0;
    while (<$fh>) {
        $count++ if /\S/;                  # count non-blank lines
        my @fields = split;                # split on whitespace
        for (0 .. $#fields) {
            $sum[$_] += $fields[$_];       # sum columns
        }
    }
    say $data;                             # file name
    say join "\t",            # 3. ...join them with tab and print
        map $_/$count,        # 2. ...for each sum, divide by count
        @sum;                 # 1. Take list of sums...
}
```

Output:

```
mean/A/data.txt
-72.354355      0.552015        56.297505       1.77814 -0.845845       0.029485        -16.88618       1.408235
mean/B/data.txt
-142.354355     0.552015        56.297505       1.77814 -0.845845       0.029485        -16.88618       1.408235
mean/C/data.txt
-72.354355      17.152015       56.297505       1.77814 -0.845845       0.029485        -16.88618       1.408235
```

Comment: Thank you, the script works perfectly! Also, thank you for the commented code, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Perl expert but this worked for me. It prints the results to terminal. Or you could redirect it to a file if you want or directly write to a file instead of printing to terminal.

```
use 5.28.2;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my ($inf, @sum);
for my $dir (glob "/mainDirectory/*"){ # finds files/subdirectories
    if (! -d $dir) {
        next;        # keeps only directories
    }
    $inf= "$dir/data.txt";
    say "$inf";
    find(\&sum_columns, $inf);
}
  
sub sum_columns{
    open (IN,  "<", "$inf" )   or die "Cannot open file.\n $!";
    while (<IN>){
        my $line = $_;
        chomp $line;
        my @columns = split(/\s+/,$line);    
        for my $item (0 .. $#columns){
            $sum[$item] += $columns[$item];
            }
    }
    say "@sum";
    @sum=();
}
```

Comment: This use of `File::Find` makes the module itself redundant. It just searches one file.

Comment: `for my $file (glob "maindir/*/data.txt") { sum_columns($_) }` perhaps. Use a lexical `@sum` in the subroutine, not a global. Same with `$inf`. `while (my $line = <IN>)`. If you split on `' '` instead, you don't need to chomp. Also, I do believe you forgot to divide the sum to get the average. You also do not need to put quotes around a single variable `say $inf` is fine. Maybe use a lexical file handle instead of a global, `my $fh`.

Comment: You're welcome. That's not my downvote btw,